# Halachos of psil techelet

Tags: techeles

Does the murex, which was found recently, contain the actual techelet? If there's a safek whether it really is or isn't ,is there any harm in wearing it? Like, would it posel the tzitzis?

Comment: Hi David and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Can you provide more information (perhaps a link?) about this recent find?  Thanks.

Comment: ...among other techelet questions